# Ajax modal popup with repeater control

Tags: ajax, toolkit

I created a repeater it has a column called **comment** on click of a comment icon, a AJAX Modal Popup comes out were user can enter the comments,

now the problem is AJAX Modalpopup comes out and disappear immediately , i dont know wats wrong in that

when i make targetcontrolid attribute of AJAX modal popup pointing to a button it works properly.but from the repeater item it does not.

i feel that this issue is related to okcontrolid and cancelcontrolid.

can anybody help me in sorting this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, ModalPopup was disappearing because postback was happening,now im returning false to onclick event after showing Modalpopup

All is well now. take care.